# How to specify the destination URL when restoring

Tags: stsadm, restore

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. And I am using publishing portal template.

I have a source web site called `http://server1/site1`, and I want to restore it to another machine whose URL is `http://server2/site2`.

I want to know in `stsadm -o restore`, how to specify the destination changed URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
stsadm -o restore -url http://server2/site2
```

This is assuming that you are restoring a site collection (which typically wouldn't have a URL like that).The majority of the links in the site collection are server relative links that will take on the URL of the web application where you are restoring.Note there could be many leftover links that are absolute and will need to be changed manually.For instance, if you create a list based on the Links template or documents that link to other documents in the site.

Comment: 1. "This is assuming that you are restoring a site collection" -- do you mean http://server1/site1 should be a site collection or http://server2/site2 should be a site collection or both? 2. How to check if http://server1/site1 is a site collection or not -- if it is not a site collection, what it could be?

Comment: Well, typically site collections either start at the root (i.e. http://server1) or they are under a managed path (i.e. http://server1/sites/site1). To find out there are two options: You can navigate to the site, go to the site settings menu, and look on the right hand site for the section Site Collection Administration to have a number of links to administer a site collection. Alternatively, you could look in the central server administration in the Site Collection list underneath your current Web Application.

Comment: George - Since you haven't been able to pick up a book to learn some of the SharePoint basics yet, this recent blog post I have might help explain some of the structural containers within SharePoint and how they interact.  http://nextconnect.blogspot.com/2010/01/sharepoint-site-topology-planning.html

Comment: Thanks MBSurf! What do you mean "look on the right hand site"? I am confused.

Comment: Question answered!